# What command do I do to make someone loop back to a specific place in my code?

Tags: python

I am making a text based game. I am moving along, but I am stumped on how to make specific choices bring you back to where you need to make the choice. Currently, the current plan I am doing is to make the right answers bring you to the rest of the game, while the incorrect questions bring you nowhere, and you have to restart the program entirely, but it isn't very fun to have to slog through the parts I have already done every single time I get a wrong choice.

```
ruintalk = input ()
if ruintalk == '1':
    print ('"Rude!" the old man shouts, "I knew you were just like the rest of them." The old man storms out as fast as his frail legs can take him. You never hear from him again and later die of lumbago and are buried in a paupers grave. Dont insult the old man or ask stupid questions. Hes kind of a dick so just roll with it and restart the game.')
```

What command should I put to bring me back to `input()`?

Comment: What if just put this code into infinite loop `while True:` and make `break` when exit condition was reached?

Answer (score 0):

Loops are what can you help you with that. "while" loops particularly in this case. "while" loops keep iterating through a block of code till the condition is true.
Here is an example demonstrating their use -

```python
while True:
  ruintalk = input()
  if ruintalk == correct_answer:
    break # This will break the iteration
```

This block of code will keep iterating until break statement is called. Alternatively, what you can do is have a variable set as True and set it to false once the correct answer is entered. Here is an example showing this -

```python
run = True
while run:
  ruintalk = input()
  if ruintalk == correct_answer:
    run = False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to build, you might want to make your input a function to be called.  You can then build loops for different scenarios and your input will happen in a statement:

```
def userInput():
     r = input()
     r = r.lower() #I like doing this to simplify how I handle user input in the code
     return(r)

while sceneComplete is False:
     print("Something to setup the scene.  What do you want to do, user??? (X/Y/Z)?")
     action = userInput()
     if action == "x":
          do the x thing
     elif action == "y":
          do the y thing
     elif action == "z":
          sceneComplete = True
     else:
          print("You broke the rules and an ogre kills you ....")
```